# MUI: Change text based on render width

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a React app using Material UI 5 components. It's responsive, and I want to potentially change the actual text based on available display space.  For instance, if the space is large I want to display "William Jefferson Clinton", if it's medium "Bill Clinton" and if it's really small then just "42".  Size is a relative thing, depending on the font, letter spacing, etc.  So is there a good way in React, MUI, or Typescript to determine how large something will be when it renders, then choose text accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Media queries would do. MUI like bootstrap has a css override functionality that can be used. So adding the media queries to the React App.css file or any custom stylesheet connected to the MUI would let the react app make the changes accordingly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries